# Control where the Android soft keyboard appears on the screen?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is there a way to control where the soft keyboard appears on the screen? Assuming it takes the whole width, I would like to be able to specify a height so that the keyboard shows on the top half of the screen. Is this possible?

Currently I'm just showing the keyboard using `SoftInputMode` in the manifest file.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

Comment: Please try android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't change anything. The keyboard remains at the bottom. And I don't see how that would let me set a y-value to specify the height.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" attribute and also apply this attribute in the previous activity of current activity in which the keyboard is opened.

Comment: ? I don't want the keyboard to be hidden, I want to specify its position on the screen!